# Auto-Save Attachment does not download the attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

can someone advise what have I done wrong on here? It is not picking up the emails the way it should (i.e. automatically download the attachments into a folder). There is no error messages, but simply no action (I went F8 but would not notice any irregularities).

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Only act if it's a MailItem
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item

    'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
        If (Msg.SenderName = "test123@gmail.com") And _
        (Msg.Subject = "Test123") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

    'Set folder to save in.
    Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim Att As String

    'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
    Const attPath As String = "C:\Test\Test1\"

    ' save attachment
   Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
    Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
    myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

   Msg.UnRead = False
End If
End If


ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Also, when I'm trying to F8 for errors, the VBA only goes through the first part of the code i.e. `Private Sub Application_Startup()`, I'm unable to test the other part `{Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)}` cos the VBA simply denies going through it line by line (no error pop-ups or anything, it simply is not picking up the lines)

Comment: When debugging does it reach, and action, the `SaveAsFile` statement? What is the value of `attPath & Att` at that point? Is it correct?

Comment: Setup a filter to loop thu items you want

Comment: You still having issue?

Comment: @0m3r yup. To start with, my code didn't work in the first place, so I'm guessing just adding a loop wouldn't simply solve the issue, not sure tho? I have a manual solution whereby I have to initiate the code myself, but I thought that it would be more efficient if it could execute automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att
```

You are always picking attachment no 1, which might be something else than you think. Add a `For Each` around this, and you'll hopefully get some better results.

Comment: There is only one attachment anyway. It's a .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is this condition:

```
If (Msg.SenderName = "test123@gmail.com")
```

The MailItem.SenderName property returns the *display name* of the sender, which may not be the actual email address. You should be checking the MailItem.SenderEmailAddress property instead.

If the email you're trying to match is an Exchange address (ie, it's from someone in your office's Outlook account), the MailItem.SenderEmailAddress will return an incomprehensible string that you'll need to resolve to an actual email. In that case, you'd need to check the MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress property instead.

For that reason, I like to use an "emailMatches" function that checks both scenarios. Then your condition would be something like:

```
If emailMatches(Msg, "test123@company.com")
```

Here's the function I use:

```
Function emailMatches(mItem As Object, addressToMatch As String) As Boolean

    Dim goAhead As Boolean
    goAhead = False

    If UCase(mItem.SenderEmailAddress) = UCase(addressToMatch) Then
        goAhead = True
    ElseIf Left(mItem.SenderEmailAddress, 5) = "/O=EX" Then
        If UCase(mItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress) = UCase(addressToMatch) Then
            goAhead = True
        End If
    End If

    emailMatches = goAhead

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, and how would I embed your function into my current code? What my code supposed to do, was to automatically download the file from a specific sender and drop it in the location on the drive. The file is .csv and it is the only attachment in the email (there is no photos or signatures attached in the email).

Comment: Literally just replace (Msg.SenderName = "test123@gmail.com") with (emailMatches(Msg, "test123@gmail.com")). And copy/paste the Function itself under the rest of your code.

Comment: Hi, I must be doing something wrong. I have replaced the line and pasted the Function (as you have provided) below: ErrorHandler: MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description Resume ProgramExit

Comment: Get rid of the "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler" line and tell me what error you're actually getting.

Comment: I have but the thing is that even when I do so, the VBA does not go line by line (F8) in "Private SuB". It only goes through "Private WithEvents" code and never through the 2nd part of it [as if the 2nd part of the code did not exist].

Comment: You need to paste the new function after "End Sub"

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and am still unable to use F8, it simply does not pick-up the code at all (other than Private Sub Application_Startup()), which does absolutely nothing. Thanks